# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'

Tags: python, exception

I have the following code in order to create a socket:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys

try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Error message: ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit();
print 'Socket created!'
```

but I have the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Comment: You have an error in `except` statement

Comment: @frostnational: true, but that's not the cause of the exception here.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it? I am new with python really..thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *different* module named `socket` on your path. You did not import the stdlib module because it is being masked.

Print out the filename of the masking module to locate it, then rename it:

```
print socket.__file__
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your python's file name, don't use the file name that are same with python's module (e.g socket.py, etc)